# $a_n, b_n$ bounded, $a_n+b_n=1$,$z_n\to a$ and $t_n\to a$, then $(a_nz_n+b_nt_n)\to a$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

I must show that if $a_n, b_n$ are bounded such that $a_n+b_n=1$, and if $z_n\to a$ and $t_n\to a$, then $(a_nz_n+b_nt_n)\to a$

My idea was:

$$(a_n+b_n)(z_n+t_n) = a_nz_n+a_nt_n+b_nz_n+b_nt_n$$

I also tried to use the fact that since $z_n$ and $t_n$ converge, then they're limited, bu I couldn't find a good algebraic manipulation to show that $|a_nz_n+b_nt_n-a|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Write 
$$a = (a_n + b_n)a.$$
Then evaluate the difference:
\begin{align*}
& |a_nz_n + b_nt_n - a| \\
= & |a_nz_n + b_nt_n - (a_n + b_n)a| \\
= & |a_n(z_n - a) + b_n(t_n - a)| \\
\leq & |a_n||z_n - a| + |b_n||t_n - a| \\
\leq & \cdots.
\end{align*}

Comment: $a = aa_n + ab_n$, then $a = a_n\lim z_n+b_n\lim t_n = \lim (a_n z_n + b_n t_n)$?

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: @user335283 I added more details, you can finish the argument by using the boundedness and convergence of two sequences. Stay with the $\epsilon$-$N$ argument.